# Rolling back transaction with aspect in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-transactions

I am new to the concept of Aspect-Oriented Programming. I am writing this following aspect using AspectJ in my spring boot application:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

  private final AspectUtil aspectUtil;

  public MyAspect(AspectUtil aspectUtil)) {
    this.aspectUtil = aspectUtil;
  }

  @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
  public void applicationServicePointcut() {
  }
  @AfterReturning(value = ("applicationServicePointcut()"))
  public void process(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    HttpServletRequest request = aspectUtil.getRequest();
    aspectUtil.getHttpVerb(request);
    processUtil(request, joinPoint);
  }

  public void processUtil(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

All of the services defined in my application are annotated with `@Transactional`, one example is given below:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyService {
 ..
}
```

So, here my question is if any exception I throw from my aspect as defined above, then would the associated transaction in the service layer get rolled back?

Actually, my goal is to roll back the entire transaction in case, any exception occurs at this aspect.

Answer (score 1):

An example for a similar requirement [1.4.8. Advising Transactional Operations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-applying-more-than-just-tx-advice) is available in the documentation.

Exerpt :

> The ordering of advice is controlled through the Ordered interface.
> .........
> The result of the preceding configuration is a fooService bean that
> has profiling and transactional aspects applied to it in that order.
> If you want the profiling advice to run after the transactional advice
> on the way in and before the transactional advice on the way out, you
> can swap the value of the profiling aspect bean’s order property so
> that it is higher than the transactional advice’s order value...

Please do go through : [Advice Ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) to understand the concept better and control the order of advice.

Also go through the conceptual view of calling a method on a transactional proxy:
[image]

Basically the idea would be to throw the exception from the custom aspect that should result in the rollback from the `Transaction Advisor`.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is it depends. Aspects are ordered in Spring, meaning that they run with a specific order. That means that if your aspect is set to run before the `transactional` aspect, then no transaction will be created and there would be nothing to actually rollback.

On the other hand, if you set this to run after the transaction aspect and it indeed throws an exception, this would automatically mean that the transaction would have ran and would be committed.

I believe you need to check on ordering of aspects to find the pattern that suits your needs the best.